# get key of max value in dictionary when value is list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-analysis

```
{'APPLE': [0.12, 0.0], 'ORANGE': [0.5, 0.0]}
```

I want to check all values in each list and see the largest one. In this case, it is 0.5 which corresponds to the key "ORANGE" so I want to return "ORANGE". How can I do this? I would prefer not to iterate through everything again/make a new dict since I am already doing this in the previous steps of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin `max()` operator with a `lambda` function

```
result = max(d.items(), key=lambda item: max(item[1]))
```

The `result` of this statement is a `tuple`

```
('BATTERY', [0.5, 0.0])
```

Where you can simply take the first element - the key

see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/268285/timeline) for the simpler case

Comment: Sorry, got that wrong. You can still call `max` on the dict only (not its items) and get the key as result right away: `max(d, key=lambda k: max(d[k]))`

Answer (score 0):

I can't any other way except this one:

```
In [22]: d
Out[22]: {'DISPLAY': [0.12, 0.0], 'BATTERY': [0.5, 0.0]}

In [23]: key = None
    ...: largest = 0
    ...: for item in d:
    ...:     if max(d[item]) > largest:
    ...:         largest = max(d[item])
    ...:         key = item
    ...:

In [24]: key
Out[24]: 'BATTERY'

In [25]: largest
Out[25]: 0.5
```